# A test of faith, or better said the lack of faith

Tags: culture, religion

Setting: 
An alternate reality during medieval times where Europe is divided by two factions. **Faction1:** A highly religious Christian (with Islamic/Jewish influences) VS **Faction 2:** a Mainly atheistic (with some Norse/Germanic pagan influences). Both factions are made up out of several relative independent states with their own armed forces but both also have an joint army that operates outside of these states jurisdiction.

After a long period of hostile peace espionage becomes more important, but how would the **Faction2** army remove possible infiltrates from **Faction1**?

A way to prove that they themselves are not religious nor would any of that religion being willing to associate themselves with the person in question. Without it conflicting with the Norse/Germanic background of **Faction2**. Preferably in a sort of ritualistic way.

Comment: Made a trap with a marking "God will protect anyone who enter". Atheist will know there is no god so there's no protection and you will die. Religious people will believe and walk straight into thousands swords. With ANTS!

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY, million of believers wear personal protection equipment at work every day.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY An atheist would enter as well. If there is no protection but a religious person thinks there is, the assumption would be that there is no danger. They would walk right into your trap while laughing at the sign

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica Atheist would read "everyone else need to wear PPE".

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Installing lightning rods on churches is a shown of pretty low faith.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY You are assuming that they believe in a god that solves their problems and protects them from danger, neither of the religions mentioned in the questions believes that. In fact, I don't think such a religion exists

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica All three: Christianity, Judaism and Islam have it. It's called Guardian angel and can be either summoned by prayer or send by god himself. And in all three they work by either protecting from danger or preventing from doing things that might harm you. If you are in harmed then you are Hiob and you should roll with it.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY You can ask God, or angels for protection, but bad things may happen to you anyway. No religion claims absolute protection from harm even if you are a saint.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica That's christianity. If you are a saint and bad things happen to you it's because god is testing you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102415/discussion-between-luis-reinstate-monica-and-szczerzo-kly).

Comment: Many have voted to close as off-topic, I however voted to close as lacks detail and information, for example how do you define an atheist with Norse/Germanic influences - is this some veiled reference to Nazis? Highly religious Christian with Islamic and Jewish influences - how would this work in light of there already being [hundreds of christian denominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominations_by_number_of_members) each with markedly different dogmas and practices. Voted to close as insufficient detail to answer.

Answer (score 12):

In short, **you can't**.  In an espionage situation there would be devout religious who would lie and willingly go through any ritual to "prove" they are athiests, and use the "greater good" justification for it.

Even if 99.999% of the religious in Faction 1 would refuse to lie and instead be tortured and killed, that leaves 0.001% who are apt to be spies.  This is one of the big problems with espionage - *group dynamics and stereotypes can't be relied on!*

USSR spies pledged allegiance to the US flag and signed papers denouncing communism; American spies have committed numerous crimes *against* America to keep their cover; athiests have prayed to God and Jews have eaten pigs.  Even if *most* people in these groups would not do these things, *some* would, and those *some* people could be spies.

Frankly, your approach isn't going to work to weed out spies.  Ironically, this type of witch-hunt actually *hurts* Faction 2 by making everyone paranoid of each other.

Instead, stick to the ways spies are traditionally discovered: require *many years* of allegiance before allowing someone anywhere close to high-ranking positions.  Implement confidentiality rules, and checks and balances.  Forbid secret documents from leaving secure facilities, and have guards and watch-dogs trained to spot and capture anything leaving.  Do routine follow ups on important agents, making sure they don't talk about their work to friends or family.  Have routine training.

In the end, *you can't stop spies*, but what you can do is *stop them from getting important info*.  You can spy on the local baker with his emotional shit-show of a family all you want; but you'll never get our country's military movements or strategies! Also, have fallbacks in place to mitigate the rare circumstances where information is captured.

Edit - can't believe I forgot about honeypots.  Every country has traps that look like legitimate government facilities / secrets - and the people working there might even believe they are working with confidential information.  But it's all lies from higher up.  These "easier-to-get" entry points would be obvious ways to trap and track spies, as a fresh spy in your country is likely to go for an *achievable* target over spending decades with their fingers crossed to *maybe* be a janitor in a government facility.

Answer (score 4):

## Shibboleth

The original [shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth) being the word shibboleth and the distinction of a regional accent, but the modern principle being something that's unique to a faction in a way that can't be transferred by password.

In the case of distinguishing religions that's most easily done by playing on the actual religions themselves. Often when two groups are up against each other the rules of one expressly forbid some of the customs of the other. See "seething a kid in its mother's milk" and other seemingly arbitrary laws for examples.

What should consider is something along these lines that one faction frowns on or forbids and the other enjoys with relish. For your scenario I'd consider starting with excessive consumption of alcohol.

Comment: This doesn't work with espionage, a spy would do it anyway, then ask god for forgiveness. The head of that alternate church would probably hand them their version of a papal bull.

Comment: @LuisReinstateMonica, a good spy will always get past you, a really good spy is probably a subverted member of your close advisors.

Comment: But with this any spy will get past you, not just the good ones. You just have to tell your spies to perform any forbidden action to maintain their cover. It doesn't require any training

Answer (score 1):

Take a page from North Korea's book.  Be extremely strict with entrance and exit controls.  Let in no one you haven't vetted, including investigating their friends and family.  Religion is social, if someone's family and friends are believers, it's likely they are too.

As for your own citizens, outlaw the religion under penalty of familial extermination.  As I said above, the odds are quite good that a religious person's close associates are also religious.  So it would be wise to kill them all.

The other answers are correct that you'll never catch all of them, but you don't need to, at least not all at once.  You just need a system that catches some high percentage, no immigration, and the willpower to enforce this system for 3-4 generations.  The religion should be dead by then.